# If an abelian group has subgroups of orders $m$ and $n$, respectively, then it has a subgroup whose order is $\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups

I'm solving **Exercise 2.5.26** from *Topics in Algebra* by Herstein. Could you please verify if my attempt is fine or contains logical mistakes?

> Let $G$ be an abelian group and $H,K$ its subgroups of orders $m$ and $n$ respectively. Then $G$ has a subgroup of order $\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)$.

---

**My attempt:** First, we prove a simple lemma

> *Lemma*: Let $G$ be an abelian group and $H,K$ its subgroups such that $o(H)= m$,  $o(K|)= n$, and $H \cap K = \{1\}$. Then the $o(H \lor K) = mn$ where $H \lor K$ is the smallest subgroup containing both $H$ and $K$.

*Proof:* Because $G$ is abelian, $H \lor K =\{hk \mid h \in H \text{ and } k \in K\}$. Let $a,b \in H$ and $x,y \in K$ such that $ax = by$. Then $a^{-1}b = xy^{-1} \in H \cap K$ and thus $a^{-1}b =1$. Consequently, $a=b$ and $x=y$. The result then follows.

Come back to our general case, let $\operatorname{lcm}(m,n) = p_1^{n_1} \cdots p_k^{n_k}$ where $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ are prime numbers. For each $i$, we pick $C_i$ from the set $\{C \in \{H, K\} \mid p_i^{n_i} \text{ divides } o(C)\}$. By below **Sylow theorem** for abelian groups (in which I use *first isomorphism theorem* to give a simple proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3765452/a-simple-proof-of-sylow-theorem-for-abelian-groups)),

> Let $G$ be an abelian group, $p$ a prime number, and $n$ a natural number. If $o(G)$ is divisible by $p^n$, then $G$ has a subgroup of order $p^n$.

we have $G$ has a subgroup $G_i$ with $o(G_i) = p_i^{n_i}$ for each $i$. Notice that $G_i \cap G_j = \{1\}$ for all $i \neq j$. Then the result follows by applying our *Lemma* repeatedly.

---

**Update:** Thanks to @aschepler for pointing out my typo. The correct version should be

we have $\color{blue}{C_i}$ has a subgroup $G_i$ with $o(G_i) = p_i^{n_i}$ for each $i$. Notice that $G_i \cap G_j = \{1\}$ for all $i \neq j$. Then the result follows by applying our *Lemma* repeatedly.

Comment: (+1) Your attempt is correct as far as I can see.

Comment: Is $C_i$ an element or a subgroup? "$C \in \{H,K\}$" doesn't really make since either way. "$C_i \in H \cup K$" would name an element, but it's not generally true an element of the needed order exists. Probably simplest to say $C_i$ is a subgroup of either $H$ or $K$ with $o(C) = p_i^{n_i}$, which exists by the quoted theorem of Sylow.

Comment: @aschepler, it's a typo. Please see my edit.

Comment: Oh, I see. You really do mean that $C_i=H$ or $C_i=K$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}$One possibility is to use the formula
$$
o(H K)
=
\frac{o(H) \cdot o(K)}{o(H \cap K)},
$$
then note that since $H \cap K \le H, K$, by Lagrange
$$
o(H \cap K) \mid o(H), o(K),
$$
so that
$$
o(H \cap K) \mid \gcd(o(H), o(K)),
$$
and finally recall that $\gcd(x, y) \cdot \lcm(x, y) = x y$.

With this you obtain that $G$ has a subgroup of order *a multiple of* the lcm, so you will have to know that the converse of Lagrange's theorem holds in a finite abelian subgroup.